# On rigidity theorem in Milne's "Abelian varieties"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The rigidity theorem states that for a regular map $\alpha:V\times W\rightarrow U$, and assume that $V$ is complete and that $V\times W$ is geometrically irreducible. And two “coordinate axes” contracts to a point, then this forces the whole space to contracts to the point.

I'm considering the following example. For $V=W=\mathbb{A}^1$, let $R=\{xy*f+c|f\in k[x,y],\,c\in k\}$ be a ring and $V\times W\rightarrow spec(R)$ would be a map contracting $({0}\times\mathbb{A}^1)\cup(\mathbb{A}^1\times{0})$ to a point. One can think $spec(R)$ as the "smash product" of two $\mathbb{A}^1$. So based on this example there are two claimes: 1. You can not take a similar construction for $V=\mathbb{P}^1,\,W=\mathbb{A}^1$ or 2. the proposed map is not regular. So which one is true?

Comment: 1. You should state the full theorem (and include reference to which theorem in this text) - it's impossible to tell the full precise result you're talking about here. 2. This map is clearly regular and it seems that claim 1 would be wrong (it contradicts the result as you've written it in the first paragraph), but there might be some assumption in the theorem you're citing that you didn't actually write in the post here.